# Is it possible to run ML Kit in Robolectric unit tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, google-mlkit

I'm curious whether it's possible to run [Google ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit) in [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) unit tests. If I try, I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: MlKitContext has not been initialized

The same test runs perfectly if I run it as an instrumented test (with AndroidJUnit4).

Comment: Could you try initializing MLKitContext in your robolectric test before every test case and deleting it after each test case? mlkitContext. = MlKitContext.initialize(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()); and mlkitContext.delete();

Comment: Thank you @ChenxiSong! I have no such error with your suggestion! Unfortunately, I still can't run my ML Kit implementation, because now I face another issue. I'll let you know once I could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

> Please use androidTest instead.

is the official answer from Google

ref: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/issues/251